# Are the square and the maximum of distribution functions a distribution function?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

> Let $F$ and $G$ be (one dimensional) distribution functions. Decide which
>   of the following are distribution functions.
>
> (a) $F^2$,
>
> (b) $H$, where $H(t) = \max \{F(t),G(t)\}$.
>
> Justify your answer.

I know the definition and properties of distribution function but I could not solve the problem in rigid way

Comment: Hint:  If $X$ and $Y$ are _independent_ random variables with identical cumulative probability distribution function (CDF) $F(t)$, and $Z = \max\{X,Y\}$, what is the CDF of $Z$, that is, what is $F_Z(t) = P\{Z \leq t\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function $F$ is a cumulative probability distribution function on $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if the following are true:

- $F(x)\to0$ as $x\to-\infty$;
- $F(x)\to1$ as $x\to+\infty$;
- $F$ is non-decreasing, i.e. whenever $a<b$ then $F(a)\le F(b)$.
- $F$ is right-continuous.

So ask yourself whether those are true of $F^2$ and of $\max\{F,G\}$ if they are true of $F$ and $G$.

Answer (score 0):

(a)$F^2$: Since $F$ is non-decreasing ,$F^2$ is also non-decreasing.
Since $F$ is right continuous,$F^2$ is also  right continuous and Since $F(X)\to 0$ as $x\to -\infty$ ,$F^2(X)\to 0$ as $x\to -\infty$ and lastly since $F(X)\to 1$ as $x\to \infty$ $F^2(X)\to 1$ as $x\to \infty$.Hence $F^2$ is a distribution function.

(b)Similarly, $H$ is also satisfying all criteria of distribution functions.Hence $H$ is a distribution function.

Comment: ultimately I understand that the problem.I am stuck because I am not writing anything .Whenever I start writing it is solved . thank you all.